# 24 hours time are only showing 12 hours time

Tags: php

I'm working on my PHP as I'm making a 24 hours format for my script including the year, month and day date format. However, I have got a little problem with my code.

In my code, it shows that I have the 24 hours time which I can get the hours for 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22 and 23 which it shows as 12pm, 1pm, 2pm...etc. When I have the 24 hours which I supposed to have 00 for 12am, but I can only get is 12.

The same things it goes for 1am (hour show as 1), 2am (hour show as 2), 3am (hour show as 3).

Here is the output:

```
<tv generator-info-name="www.myscript.com/xmltv">
<channel id="101 ABC FAMILY">
<display-name>101 ABC FAMILY</display-name>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140406153000" stop="20140406183000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140406183000" stop="20140406210000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140406210000" stop="20140406120000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140406120000" stop="20140406123000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140406123000" stop="2014040610000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="2014040610000" stop="2014040613000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="2014040613000" stop="2014040623000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="2014040623000" stop="2014040630000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="2014040630000" stop="">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
</channel>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
   <?php
   ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
   $errmsg_arr = array();
   $errflag = false;
   $link;
   include ('simple_html_dom.php');
   $html = file_get_html("http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php?channels=" . $channel . "&id=" . $my_id);

   $time1 = $html_two->find('span[id=time1]',0)->plaintext;
   $title1 = $html_two->find('span[id=title1]',0)->plaintext;

   $time1 = explode(" ", $time1);
   $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time1[0]);
   $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
   $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

   if($time1[1] == "PM")
   {
     $time1[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";
   } 
   else 
   {
     $time1[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";
   }
   $program_list[$count]['start_time1'] = $time1[0];
   $program_list[$count]['title1'] = $title1;

   //time2
   $time2 = $html_two->find('span[id=time2]', 0)->plaintext;
   $title2 = $html_two->find('span[id=title2]', 0)->plaintext;

   $time2 = explode(" ", $time2);
   $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time2[0]);
   $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
   $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

   if($time2[1] == "PM")
   {
     $time2[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";
   } 
   else 
   {
     $time2[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";
   }    
   $program_list[$count]['end_time1'] = $time2[0];
   $program_list[$count]['start_time2'] = $time2[0];
   $program_list[$count]['title2'] = $title2;

   //time3
   $time3 = $html_two->find('span[id=time3]', 0)->plaintext;
   $title3 = $html_two->find('span[id=title3]', 0)->plaintext;

   $time3 = explode(" ", $time3);
   $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time3[0]);
   $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
   $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

   if($time3[1] == "PM")
   {
     $time3[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";
   } 
   else 
   {
     $time3[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";
   }    
   $program_list[$count]['end_time2'] = $time3[0];
   $program_list[$count]['start_time3'] = $time3[0];
   $program_list[$count]['title3'] = $title3;

   //time4
   $time4 = $html_two->find('span[id=time4]', 0)->plaintext;
   $title4 = $html_two->find('span[id=title4]', 0)->plaintext;

   $time4 = explode(" ", $time4);
   $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time4[0]);
   $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
   $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

   if($time4[1] == "PM")
   {
     $time4[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";
   } 
   else 
   {
     $time4[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";
   }    
   $program_list[$count]['end_time3'] = $time4[0];
   $program_list[$count]['start_time4'] = $time4[0];
   $program_list[$count]['title4'] = $title4;

   //time5
   $time5 = $html_two->find('span[id=time5]', 0)->plaintext;
   $title5 = $html_two->find('span[id=title5]', 0)->plaintext;

   $time5 = explode(" ", $time5);
   $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time5[0]);
   $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
   $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

   if($time5[1] == "PM")
   {
     $time5[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";
   } 
   else 
   {
     $time5[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";
   }
   $program_list[$count]['end_time4'] = $time5[0];
   $program_list[$count]['start_time5'] = $time5[0];
   $program_list[$count]['title5'] = $title5;

   //time6
   $time6 = $html_two->find('span[id=time6]', 0)->plaintext;
   $title6 = $html_two->find('span[id=title6]', 0)->plaintext;

   $time6 = explode(" ", $time6);
   $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time6[0]);
   $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
   $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

   if($time6[1] == "PM")
   {
     $time6[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";
   } 
   else 
   {
     $time6[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";
   }    
   $program_list[$count]['end_time5'] = $time6[0];
   $program_list[$count]['start_time6'] = $time6[0];
   $program_list[$count]['title6'] = $title6;

   //time7
   $time7 = $html_two->find('span[id=time7]', 0)->plaintext;
   $title7 = $html_two->find('span[id=title7]', 0)->plaintext;

   $time7 = explode(" ", $time7);
   $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time7[0]);
   $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
   $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

   if($time7[1] == "PM")
   {
     $time7[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";
   }
   else 
   {
     $time7[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";
   }    
   $program_list[$count]['end_time6'] = $time7[0];
   $program_list[$count]['start_time7'] = $time7[0];
   $program_list[$count]['title7'] = $title7;

   //time8
   $time8 = $html_two->find('span[id=time8]', 0)->plaintext;
   $title8 = $html_two->find('span[id=title8]', 0)->plaintext;

   $time8 = explode(" ", $time8);
   $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time8[0]);
   $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
   $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

   if($time8[1] == "PM")
   {
     $time8[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";
   } 
   else 
   {
     $time8[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";
   }    
   $program_list[$count]['end_time7'] = $time8[0];
   $program_list[$count]['start_time8'] = $time8[0];
   $program_list[$count]['title8'] = $title8;

   //time9   
   $time9 = $html_two->find('span[id=time9]', 0)->plaintext;      
   $title9 = $html_two->find('span[id=title9]', 0)->plaintext;

   $time9 = explode(" ", $time9);
   $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time9[0]);
   $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
   $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

   if($time9[1] == "PM")
   {
     $time9[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";
   }
   else 
   {
     $time9[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";
   }    
   $program_list[$count]['end_time8'] = $time9[0];
   $program_list[$count]['start_time9'] = $time9[0];
   $xml .= "<channel id='" . $my_id. " " . $channel . "'>";
   $xml .= "<display-name>" . $my_id. " " . $channel; 
   $xml .= "</display-name>";
   $xml .= "<programme channel='" . $my_id. " " . $channel . "' start='" . $program_list[$i]['start_time1'] . "' stop='" . $program_list[$i]['end_time1'] . "'>";
   $xml .= '<title lang="en">';
   $xml .= '</title>';
   $xml .= '<sub-title lang="en">';
   $xml .= '</sub-title>';
   $xml .= '<desc lang="en">';
   $xml .= '</desc>';
   $xml .= '<category lang="en">';
   $xml .= '</category>';
   $xml .= '</programme>';
```

As you can see on the start time tag, e.g: 20140406183000. The 2014 is the year, 04 is the month, 06 is the day of the month, 18 is the hour, 30 is the mins and 00 is the seconds. If you look at the hours, you will know what hours are correct and what hours are not correct. What you can see, I have got some of the hours which are not set to correct. The hours that are not correct which it is 12am (supposed to be 00), 1am (supposed to be 01), 2am (supposed to be 02) and so on.

Can you please tell me what I would need to do to fix the problem?

Comment: Use DateTime() when working with dates

Comment: raw time and date manipulation is a bad idea

Comment: You really need to get this down to a more concise example for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: @JohnConde and Dagon thank you for your advice, can you please tell me what change I need to make in order to get the 24 hours clock?

Comment: I give up, man.  Your questions reflect a lack of knowledge about how the language works in any fundamental manner.  I wish you luck.

Comment: hey!!! why did you delete your post? I need that code, i'm sorry for lack of knowledge but I'm getting there. You need the paitence. Oh and I was about to mark your answer! :(

Comment: I'll undelete it as I want to be helpful.  I just didn't want to leave a partial answer live. :)

Comment: And as a lame excuse, I am a bit brain-fried with this Java app for Android I am working on.  Very complicated and a bit too irritating, lol.  I hope you get what you need!

Comment: Thank you very much, so sorry about that. I didn't think where I should input the code. Looks like I have got it now, I think I know know where it is. I was not aware where I should input the code. I think I found it. So I have marked your answer. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show my time in 24 hours format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918755/how-to-show-my-time-in-24-hours-format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is rather difficult to read, but where you have

```
((int)($hours) + 12)
```

I would replace with something like this

```
getPaddedHour((int)$hours, $time9[1]);
```

and define the function as

```
function getPaddedHour($hour, $meridian) {
  $ret = $hour;
  if ($meridian == 'AM' && $ret == 12) { 
    $ret = 0;
  } else if ($meridian == 'PM' && $ret != 12) { 
    $ret += 11;
  }
  if ($ret < 10) {
    $ret = '0'.$ret;
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

But I wholly agree with the commenters.  Trying to parse date/time on your own is a pain and unreliable, that's why there are functions made for us to use in the language.

**EDIT:** Assuming `$time2` is of the form `h:mm a` (e.g. `5:30 PM`), then `strtotime` can be used to convert to a reliable format for the current date (which you're using in your post).

For example:

```
$start_time = strtotime($html_two->find('span[id=time1]',0)->plaintext);
```

Then, later on...

```
if ($start_time !== FALSE) {
  $program_list[$count]['start_time1'] = date('YmdHis', $time);
} else {
  $program_list[$count]['start_time1'] = 'Not Available';
}
```

The if/else statement is b/c if what you are expecting from the input is not delivered, then you will need to account for it and strtotime will return false.

Comment: @Jeremey Miller Thank you very much for that, so what is the correct code for me to use to replace the `getPaddedHour((int)$hours, $time9[1]);` by using `$time1[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";`?

Comment: I understand, but can you give me an example of the actual data you receive?  Then I can suggest an appropriate alternative.

Comment: how i can give you the output for the actual data that I receive? in what line i need to put the echo to get the output?

Comment: `$time1` before you make any changes to it.

Comment: which line i need to put the echo $time1 before then?

Comment: there you go: `3:30 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM`

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the new data.  Please remember to accept answers which answer the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for updated your answer. You did not say which line I should input the following code `$start_time = strtotime($html_two->find('span[id=time1]',0)->plaintext);` and do I have to replace from this: `$time1[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";` to this: `$time1[0] = date("Ymd") . (getPaddedHour((int)$hours, $time9[1])) . $minutes . "00";`?

Comment: Where you are getting time from the external source, use the `strtotime` line (adjusted accordingly).  Where you are outputting a modification, use the if/else construct.