# How to show my time in 24 hours format

Tags: php

I'm working on my PHP which I'm displaying the year, month, day of the month and time format. I have got a little problem with my code.

In my code, it shows that it will only display the 12 hours format which I want to get the 24 hours format. When I have time, for e.g: 12am. I want to display the hours as 00, but I only get is 12 hours. The same things it goes for 1am (hour show as 1), 2am (hour show as 2), 3am (hour show as 3).

Here is the output:

```
<tv generator-info-name="www.myscript.com/xmltv">
<channel id="101 ABC FAMILY">
<display-name>101 ABC FAMILY</display-name>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140406153000" stop="20140406183000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140406183000" stop="20140406210000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140406210000" stop="20140406120000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140406120000" stop="20140406123000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="20140406123000" stop="2014040610000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="2014040610000" stop="2014040613000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="2014040613000" stop="2014040623000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="2014040623000" stop="2014040630000">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
<programme channel="101 ABC FAMILY" start="2014040630000" stop="">
<title lang="en"/>
<sub-title lang="en"/>
<desc lang="en"/>
<category lang="en"/>
</programme>
</channel>
```

Here is the PHP:

```
   <?php
   ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
   $errmsg_arr = array();
   $errflag = false;
   $link;
   include ('simple_html_dom.php');
   $html = file_get_html("http://www.mysite.com/get-listing.php?channels=" . $channel . "&id=" . $my_id);

   $time1 = $html_two->find('span[id=time1]',0)->plaintext;
   $title1 = $html_two->find('span[id=title1]',0)->plaintext;

   $time1 = explode(" ", $time1);
   $hoursMinutes = explode(":", $time1[0]);
   $hours = $hoursMinutes[0];
   $minutes = $hoursMinutes[1];

   if($time1[1] == "PM")
   {
     $time1[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";
   } 
   else 
   {
     $time1[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";
   }
   $program_list[$count]['start_time1'] = $time1[0];
   $program_list[$count]['title1'] = $title1;

   $xml .= "<channel id='" . $my_id. " " . $channel . "'>";
   $xml .= "<display-name>" . $my_id. " " . $channel; 
   $xml .= "</display-name>";
   $xml .= "<programme channel='" . $my_id. " " . $channel . "' start='" . $program_list[$i]['start_time1'] . "' stop='" . $program_list[$i]['end_time1'] . "'>";
   $xml .= '<title lang="en">';
   $xml .= '</title>';
   $xml .= '<sub-title lang="en">';
   $xml .= '</sub-title>';
   $xml .= '<desc lang="en">';
   $xml .= '</desc>';
   $xml .= '<category lang="en">';
   $xml .= '</category>';
   $xml .= '</programme>';
```

As you can see on the start time tag, e.g: 20140406183000. The 2014 is the year, 04 is the month, 06 is the day of the month, 18 is the hour, 30 is the mins and 00 is the seconds. If you look at the hours, you will know what hours are correct and what hours are not correct.

What you can see, I have got some of the hours which are not correct. The hours that are not correct which it is 12am (supposed to be 00), 1am (supposed to be 01), 2am (supposed to be 02) and so on.

Can you please tell me what I would need to do to fix the problem?

Comment: Did you try parsing the time using the built-in functions/classes? If yes - what went wrong? Same goes for generating XML.

Comment: What is the format of $time1 before you start exploding it and such? You may be able to pass it directly to strtotime() and get an integer timestamp from it, and use that to do your date() formatting as needed

Comment: @Vatev yes I did, the hours I get in return which it is: `3:30 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM 5:00 PM`. There is no problem with the parsing the time, but the code i use `$time1[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";` it did not convert the hours into 24 hours. can you help?

Comment: @Uberfuzzy the format of $time1 is only show as 12 hours. I want to display the $time1 in 24 hours format. Can you help?

Comment: @Uberfuzzy I believe that something I need to make the change into this code: `$time1[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";`. I need to make the $hours into 00 if it 12am, 01 for 1am, 02 for 2am, 03 for 3am and so on. How I can do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you could do:

```
$time_old_format = $html_two->find('span[id=time1]',0)->plaintext;
$time_new_format = date("YmdHis", strtotime($time_old_format));
```

This will parse, for example the string `12:30 AM` to `20140407003000`. (Depending on the current day of course.)

Comment: thank you very much for this, do i need to get rid of the $time1 codes inclduing the explode so i can use your code if the others dont work? would your code work if i use it?

Comment: @user3494862 Yes, you can get rid of all the explodes, just read the old format time (that you've called `$time1`), format it using `strtotime()` and `date()` as the answer shows, and insert it to the proper place (apparently `$program_list[$count]['start_time1']` in your code). And as you keep learning programming keep in mind that for common operations such as date and time formatting, there are almost always ready-made functions that you can, and should, use.

Comment: can I be able to change the date to the next day date when I have the time 00 hours?

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime()` to convert normal english textual datetime to timestamp and `date()` to display in any format you want.

```
$datetime = "03-05-2000 03:07:34 pm";
$timestamp = str_to_time($datetime);
$date = date('d M, Y H:i:s',$timestamp);  //03 May, 2000 15:07:34
```

Comment: `$time1 = $html_two->find('span[id=time1]',0)->plaintext;`
`$time1i = strtotime($time1);`
`$program_list[$count]['start_time1'] = date('YmdHis',$time1i );`

Comment: @ParagTyagi I believe that something I need to make the change into this code: `$time1[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";`. I need to make the $hours into 00 if it 12am, 01 for 1am, 02 for 2am, 03 for 3am and so on. Can you please tell me how I can do that??

Comment: get rid of that code. you are doing the wrong math for wrapping 12hour clock to 24. just feed your original id=time1 string into the strtotime() function, then use date() to get out the format you want, using the H for hours, like in the example i posted above this

Comment: do you mean i need to get rid of the follwing code `if($time1[1] == "PM")
  {
    $time1[0] = date("Ymd") . ((int)($hours) + 12) . $minutes . "00";
  } 
  else 
  {
    $time1[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";
  }`  or do i just need to get rid of the `$time1[0] = date("Ymd") . $hours . $minutes . "00";`?

Comment: yes, there are now 2 answers, and multiple comments with working examples. get rid of all your explode() calls to the $time1 value. dont do any of that splitting or math yourself. strtotime() is a magical thing that does all that for you

Comment: @Uberfuzzy Thank you very much for your help, I can see that the hours time are now working. So problem are now solved!

Comment: @Uberfuzzy can you please post the answer so i will mark your question as the answer and i will also give you the vote. Please feel to do the same in return.